# Nullpointer Exception getter, Android, Fragments, Folding Cell

Tags: java, android, list, exception

I'm getting a Nullpointer Exception on

```
viewHolder.inputvorname.setText(item.getivorname());
```

(69 in code Adapter). I didn't do quite much (maybe 4 to 5 weeks) in Android programming. I tried hardcoding content (you will see that).The code should programatically produce a new Folding Cell, filled with content. I hope you can help me:

FoldingCellListAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton; 
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;



public class FoldingCellListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private HashSet<Integer> unfoldedIndexes = new HashSet<>();


public FoldingCellListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get item for selected view
    Item item = getItem(position);
    // if cell is exists - reuse it, if not - create the new one from resource
    FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (cell == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.foldingcell_pat, parent, 
false);
        // binding view parts to view holder
        viewHolder.inputvorname = (EditText) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_inputvorname);
        viewHolder.inputname = (EditText) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_inputname);
        viewHolder.inputdate = (EditText) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_inputdate);
        viewHolder.inputtime = (EditText) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_inputtime);
        viewHolder.inputid = (EditText) cell.findViewById(R.id.np_patID);
        viewHolder.inputage = (EditText) cell.findViewById(R.id.np_patage);
        viewHolder.inputnote = (EditText) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_notizen);
        //viewHolder.pledgePrice = (Spinner) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_keimespin);
        //viewHolder.pledgePrice = (RadioGroup) 
cell.findViewById(R.id.np_colorgroup);
        cell.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // for existing cell set valid valid state(without animation)
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
            cell.unfold(true);
        } else {
            cell.fold(true);
        }
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
    }

    // bind data from selected element to view through view holder
    viewHolder.inputvorname.setText(item.getivorname());
    viewHolder.inputname.setText(item.getiname());
    viewHolder.inputdate.setText(item.getidate());
    viewHolder.inputtime.setText(item.getitime());
    viewHolder.inputid.setText(item.getiid());
    viewHolder.inputage.setText(item.getiage());
    viewHolder.inputnote.setText(item.getinote());




    return cell;
}

// simple methods for register cell state changes
public void registerToggle(int position) {
    if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position))
        registerFold(position);
    else
        registerUnfold(position);
}

public void registerFold(int position) {
    unfoldedIndexes.remove(position);
}

public void registerUnfold(int position) {
    unfoldedIndexes.add(position);
}


// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    EditText inputvorname;
    EditText inputname;
    EditText inputdate;
    EditText inputtime;
    EditText inputid;
    EditText inputage;
    EditText inputnote;
    //Spinner inputkeime;
    //RadioGroup colorgroup;
}
```

}

Item.java:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Item{
private String ivorname = "Jürgen";
private String iname = "Hans";
private String idate = "1.1.17";
private String itime = "1:1";
private String iid = "P7777";
private int iage = 1;
private String inote = "Hi";
private String ikeime = "MRSA";
private int icolor = 1;

public Item() {
}

public Item (String ivorname, String iname, String idate, String itime, String iid, int iage, String inote, String ikeime, int icolor){
    this.ivorname = ivorname;
    this.iname = iname;
    this.idate = idate;
    this.itime = itime;
    this.iid = iid;
    this.iage = iage;
    this.inote = inote;
    this.ikeime = ikeime;
    this.icolor = icolor;

}

public String getivorname() {return ivorname;}
public String getiname() {return iname;}
public String getidate() {return idate;}
public String getitime() {return itime;}
public String getiid() {return iid;}
public int getiage() {return iage;}
public String getinote() {return inote;}
public String getikeime() {return ikeime;}
public int geticolor() {return icolor;}
public void setivorname(String ivorname) {this.ivorname = ivorname;}
public void setiname(String iname) {this.iname = iname;}
public void setidate(String idate) {this.idate = idate;}
public void setitime(String itime) {this.itime = itime;}
public void setiid(String iid) {this.iid = iid;}
public void setiage(int iage) {this.iage = iage;}
public void setinote(String inote) {this.inote = inote;}
public void setikeime(String ikeime) {this.ikeime = ikeime;}
public void seticolor(int icolor) {this.icolor = icolor;}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = ivorname != null ? ivorname.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (iname != null ? iname.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (idate != null ? idate.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (itime != null ? itime.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (iid != null ? iid.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (inote != null ? inote.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (ikeime != null ? ikeime.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

public static ArrayList<Item> getTestingList() {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new Item("Peter", "Hans", "19.10.2017", "10:12", "P2546", 45, "Test 123", "MRSA, VRE", 1));
    return items;

}
```

}

patientsc.java:

```
public class patientsc extends Fragment {
View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setTitle("Alle Patienten");
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patiensl, container, false);

    // get our list view
    ListView theListView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.patientslist);

    // prepare elements to display
    final ArrayList<Item> items = Item.getTestingList();


    // create custom adapter that holds elements and their state (we need hold a id's of unfolded elements for reusable elements)
    final FoldingCellListAdapter adapter = new FoldingCellListAdapter(getContext(), items);


    // set elements to adapter
    theListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set on click event listener to list view
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            // toggle clicked cell state
            ((FoldingCell) view).toggle(false);
            // register in adapter that state for selected cell is toggled
            adapter.registerToggle(pos);
        }
    });

    return myView;
}
```

}

patiensl.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/patientslist"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `item.getivorname()` is probably `null`

Comment: that what came in my mind too, so i put hardcoded content in it, but still no change. I think I got a problem creating the item, but I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: Either `item` is `null` or `inputvorname` of `viewHolder` is `null`. Can you put a breakpoint at this line and debug?

Comment: i debugged and in viewholder all are null and convert view is null. in the line with the exception, the variables are all set, so item.getivorname isn't null, it got "Peter" in it